# How do I shut off this water supply?

Tags: toilet, installation

I live in an apartment and want to install a bidet attachment. I thought shutting off the water would be the easy part like I see in the videos but it’s not so simple. I’m not sure if it’s purposely hidden from us or if I just need a tool or something. Obviously don’t want to cause any floods or leaks. I see there’s a trick to freeze it but that seems a lot less reliable. How would you know when it’s frozen enough? Really would appreciate any advice.

[image: mi]

Comment: Looks like someone took the knob off, it is usually held on with a small screw.

Comment: That does look like a shut off valve with a piece missing.  There might be a main shut off for the apartment or ask building maintenance.

Comment: I suspect that this is deliberate; the apartment owner doesn't want tenants messing with the plumbing.

Comment: @PeteBecker *Possible*, but I doubt it. The far more common use for the shutoff is "the toilet won't stop running because of problems with the flapper, etc. in the tank". And if that is combined with "the toilet is clogged" then that shutoff is the difference between "call maintenance in the morning" and "**CALL THE LANDLORD RIGHT THIS VERY SECOND!**" *Which reminds me of the time I went to synagogue and the women were lining up to use the men's bathroom with someone guarding the door to make sure no men went in. Why? Because the women's room had a running and clogged toilet. And nobody knew*

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- I didn't say it was a good idea ... <g>

Comment: *what to do, so rather than actually solve the problem they used the men's room. I went in, found the shutoff for the toilet and turned it off.*

Comment: **Don't freeze the braided hose!** Hopefully that's a keyed valve as suggested in an answer, but if you are unable to close it, you might need a building shutdown, which the  super might not like to do just so you can install a bidet ... but you can ask.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a [Loose Key supply stop](https://www.build.com/product/summary/992543?uid=4286573) that uses a key.

If you don't have the key a ratchet and socket can sometimes work.

Comment: Good call!   The key is just a square.  IDK if  these will fit but square head keys that are easy to buy and try are radiator bleed valve keys, and 4-way sillcock keys.